# SVG gradient backgrounds doesn't work

Tags: html, background, svg, internet-explorer-9

I got a problem with SVG backgrounds.

When I run my website locally on IE9 the svg-gradient shows. But when I upload my site the my webhost the gradients just don't work.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If that's the solution, put it in an answer and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

I added a .htaccess file in the same folder as my .svg files with the following content:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```