# How can I make this logo,slogan and video responsive?

Tags: html, css

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/L4znJ/

I am trying to make embed a random video and want to make it responsive.

```
<div id="full-video">
<div class="fullvid">
<div class="video" style="margin-left:16.25em;">
    <iframe width="840" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/WeYsTmIzjkw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is a simple website with a logo at the top and the slogan displayed inline with the logo and a video right below vertically on the middle of the screen. 
Also, how can I make these all responsive??
I can't test if the font face is working, i am working on localhost. If you spot any errors or if you can show me another and the best ways of doing these so, please help me fix them.

Comment: What have you tried? From the looks of it you are not familiar with responsive web design. You should look into a responsive web tutorial so you know the basics to setting the site up.

Comment: That's why I am trying to do this, to learn.

Comment: I understand but that is not the point of stackoverflow. It is a last resort resource to problems not tutorials. I am including some links to help. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/ / http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2013/02/responsive-web-design.html Pertaining to the logo, use an `svg` image type and it will be 100% responsive, look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/fwrzB/2/. That is an image and as you can see the text and everything is able to be highlighted and editable. Hover over the image to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LFpU5/

Custom edit HTML:

```
<div class="video" style="margin-left:16.25em;">
```

For:

```
<div class="video margin">
```

**CSS responsive:**

```
.margin {margin-left:16.25em;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .margin {margin-left:0;}
    .logo {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
    .banner {
        width: auto;
    }
    .video iframe,
    .video object,
    .video embed {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the margin in #video
and remove the width/height attributes from the iframe. width="840" height="480" and replace with something like the below it should be responsive

style="display:inline-block; width:100%; min-height: 250px;"

In relation to the font, if you are downloading a font and hosting it yourself you will need to enable some settings in htaccess see this post [SVG gradient backgrounds doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994230/svg-problem-webhosting)

The easier option is to use a font on https://www.google.com/fonts then you don't need to worry about any of the server stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
I did it, here: http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/tqVLX/ But now it's all the way wide and the height is always 250px. Still not what I want to achieve. I don't want it to be wide, I just want to align it vertically middle and 700-750px wide.